# Informatica Data Integration - Update rows on JDBC target that does not have primary keys created

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

Product : Informatica Cloud Data Integration

I have a JDBC target connection on a DB2 table on which I need to perform update operation if the incoming Policy number (from a SQL Server table) already exists on the target DB2 table.

My target table does not have a primary key defined and these are legacy tables where we cannot change/add keys. How can I perform update (or upsert) on a table that does not have primary key defined.

1. For relational targets, when I select 'Upsert' as Operation, I see that 'Update Columns' is populated where we can specify the columns to be used as keys for matching. This option (Update Columns) is not coming for JDBC targets when I select operation as 'Upsert'. Is it expected behavior?
2. PowerCenter allows us to override target definition inside powercenter. Does Cloud Data Integration has a similar feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informatica confirmed that cloud JDBC connection does not have upsert option. We used ODBC connection on DB2 tables and performed upsert operations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use merge in the post sql